# Nested ListBox scrolling issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox within listbox and when I try to reduce the height of the window the scrollbar for the listbox does not appears up. I want to dispaly the scrollbar on the outer listbox because the outerlistbox can have multiple innner listboxes.
here is the XAML I am using. Can anybody let me know what is the issue?

```
<ListBox Name="MasterListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200">
    <ListBoxItem >
        <ListBox Name="Child1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="testing item3" />
        </ListBox>
    </ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am getting you right, you dont want the inner listboxes to scroll.

There are two ways to achieve that:

1) Change inner listbox to ItemsPanel.
2) If you really need to preserve the inner control as ListBox you have to replace the ScrollViewer with a ContentPresenter in the Template of the inner Listbox control. See this link (it`s marked as correct answer) > http://forums.silverlight.net/t/193872.aspx/1

Comment: if i use the style mentioned in the following url it gives me a compile time error as content presenter does not support direct content

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner `listbox` to an `ItemsControl` then the scrollbars won't show up in it.